# Automatic, one-time image fade-in with set delay

Tags: jquery

As a designer with extremely limited coding experience (as of now), I was very happy to find a script for a simple slideshow that I implemented on this page: http://www.forwardthinkingmuseum.com/

Now I need something even simpler, and I have not found a new script or an idea how to stop the existing script. Here is the description of the task, as precise as I manage to express it as a non-programer:

On-load image A, sitting in a container, needs to be automatically replaced with image B, fading in after a delay that I can determine (probably around 3 seconds). This is a one-time, automatic event. Once coming into view, image B will just sit there and will link to a new page on click.

Does this make sense? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use (in your $(document).ready(function() )

```
setTimeout(fade_function, 3000);
```

and then define your function

```
function fade_function(){
   //do the fading from image a to b
```

This will be executed only once.

[Here](http://css.dzone.com/news/jquery-image-cross-fade-transi) is a tutorial for a crossfading effect with jquery